# Rails Javascript minification issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I  have a custom javascript file which i am loading in my layout.

custom.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require modules
//= require login
//= require user
```

I am loading in my layout as below. The js is getting loaded in a minified form, it seems some of jQuery calls/events are not happening at all. I am not sure whether its because of minification of files.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/custom' %>
```

I am not sure how to debug this either. Previously these files were loaded from `application.js` and none of the files were minified in big js instead were loaded separately and everything was working fine.

Now i am trying to load the `custom.js` file only for certain `modules` so loaded the corresponding `js` files in custom.js, but because of the minification its not working or i am not sure whats the problem.

In my production.rb file, below is the configuration

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Comment: I assume the issue only happens in production mode since you refer to production.rb. If you suspect that minifying is the issue you can test that by temporarily setting `config.assets.compress = false` in production.rb.

Comment: @Sharagoz: Its happening in development.

Comment: Is compression enabled in development.rb?